# Spring application in JBoss AS 7.1.1: Unexpected element: beans

Tags: spring, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to migrate a small web application from Tomcat 7 to JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final. It's based on Spring Framework 3.2.16.RELEASE and runs well in Tomcat 7.

However when I deploy it to JBoss I get the following error:

```
16:23:24,973 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "myapp.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: beans
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: beans
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:123)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:80)
    ... 6 more
```

I tried to google it, but no luck so far. Any idea?

Comment: do you have any file named *-ds.xml in your deployment?

Comment: Yes, I do...... Hmmmm, strange functionality. Thank you for the hint. Now it works. Please, publish it as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some file named *-ds.xml in your war deployment.

Probably inside WEB-INF directory
WildFly (& jboss as7+) threats this files as datasource definition and as such it is expecting certain xml structure.

In you case you probably have something else in this file that it cannot understand.
Best way is to either remove this file or just rename it to not be *-ds.xml if you need it for some config/resource in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same exception "Unexpected element: beans" for a file named '*-jms.xml'. This was occuring while deploying an existing application in JBOSS 6 EAP with additional changes related to JMS. The JMS related spring beans were added in to a new file named '*-jms.xml'. As suggested earlier, the jboss expect a defined structure for files named *-jms.xml'. Removing the '-jms' from the filename fixed the issue. The documentation on '*-jms.xml' files can be found here
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Messaging+configuration.

The error message and the root cause is same as with '*-ds.xml' files, so posting the answer under this post. Similar documentation on '*-ds.xml' can be found here https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration.